# sound recording using Naudio .Net class library in web application

Tags: c#, naudio

is it possible to record sound using Naudio (https://naudio.codeplex.com/) .net class library in C# web application ??

I have requirement to record sound (of users) in web application.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible - c# is backend (works on server) application, while your website is frontend (works on client's machine). Any ties between those two are cut after server sends rendered page to client.

The best you can get - do a recording using some sort of javascript library (though I am not sure, that those exist), and send the recorded file to server via AJAX or simple POST as a form's file element.

Oh, you could use flash/silverlight or something like that as well. Might be even easier.